# Maven cannot resolve a jar which I can see on the repository

Tags: maven, wicket

I specify wicket version 1.5-RC7 in my pom.xml. When I do a `mvn install` it complains about: `The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.wicket:wicket:jar:1.5-RC7, javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B`. So I try searching for the javax.transaction.jta-1.0.1B.jar on mvnrepository.com, and I am able to find it. Why does maven tell me it can't resolve avax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B?

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    …
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>mvnrepository</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        …       
    </dependencies>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <wicket.version>1.5-RC7</wicket.version>
        ...
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 is the default one that Maven will lookup.  You don't need to declare it again.

Can you check, when you build, which server your Maven is trying to connect? You should see something like `Downloading: http://whatever.com/path/to/dependencies.pom`.

I have just checked in maven central repo, there is no org.apache.wicket:wicket:1.5-RC7.  You have better to check if you have declared the correct dependency

For JTA, it is a bit tricky.  For quite some Java spec JARs, because of licensing issue, the actual JAR is not available in the public central Maven repo.  If you look at http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|javax.transaction|jta|1.0.1B|jar , you will see it only contains POM, but not the JAR.

There are some ways to solve:

1. If you have a Maven repo in your own company, consider getting the JAR from Sun/Oracle, and deploy it yourself
2. For JTA spec itself, JAR is available for newer version (1.1) .  Check if it is fine for you to use to latter spec
3. Switch to use Geromino spec.  It should be compatible.  http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22geronimo-spec%22%20AND%20a%3A%22geronimo-spec-jta%22

---

Edit

I have missed the wicket 1.5-RC7 in my previous search. Sorry.  After looking into the POM, it seems that it is not a JAR POM.  `org.apache.wicket:wicket:1.5-RC7` is of type `POM`, in which declares dependency to `wicket-core` artifact.

You have two ways to do:

1. Change your dependency to point to `wicket-core` (and maybe other wicket modules) instead of `wicket`.
2. Change your dependency declaration to have `<type>pom</type>`  (because default is `jar`)

I am not familiar with Wicket, but I believe method 1 is preferred.

Comment: Thanks - I will remove the default repo. First, here is [the wicket:1.5-RC7](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wicket/wicket/1.5-RC7) on the central maven repo. Second, here's what I see during my build: Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/wicket/wicket/1.5-RC7/wicket-1.5-RC7.jar

Comment: Sorry my fault, I haven't noticed that there are more than 1 page when I am searching in repo.maven.org.  Please see my update

Comment: 1) What is the difference between a `JAR POM` and of type `POM`? Is JAR POM a module that allows you download a jar on http://mvnrepository.com/? 2) Will the two ways you provided produce the same end result?

Comment: 1) In Maven, every POM has a type, by default "JAR", meaning the artifact is a JAR. Another commonly seen type is "POM" which means there is no actual artifact, and there is only the POM itself.  Normally a POM will need to use together with the corresponding artifact (except POM-type of course).  A JAR POM (which mean a POM with type "JAR") is not going to find you the corresponding JAR.  2) in your specific case, yes.  However conceptually they r different.  1 is declaring the actual dependency you are using, 2 is depending on a POM-type POM. Actual dependency is resolved transitively.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ~/.m2/settings.xml, I'm guessing you have an internal company (Nexus) repo mirror/proxy setting avoiding you fetching from internet -- and this mirror is stale.

If this is the case there are two common way to fix it: fix your internal Nexus repo so it's up to date, or bypass the Nexus repo so you fetch from the internet

Comment: The only thing I have in my ~/.m2/ is my repository directory. Is that the only way to see if I'm using a Nexus repo? If I was using a Nexus repo, how do I bypass it?

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this issue just now and resolved it. I have seen lot of questions in stack overflow related to this . Since my resolution was slightly different I am posting this answer. .

**Issue** :-Failed to execute goal on project Apigee-Edge-deploy-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project io.apigee.build-tools.enterprise4g:Apigee-Edge-deploy-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0.0: The following artifacts could not be resolved:

**Root Cause**:- The Repo had the dependency jars mentioned in the project. But the dependencies in turn had other dependencies which was not present in the repo and caused this issue. I added exclusion to the dependency and it worked.

**eg**:-

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-metadata</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>woden</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.apache.woden</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

**Reference**:-
Also checkout the very good article on maven dependencies and exclusion